# table cell Width % values changing other cell width values by itself?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="animatedwebsite.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <style>
        table, tr, td, th {
            border:1px solid black;   

        }

        table {
            width:100%;
            height:100%;


        }
        #logo {
            height:50px;
            width:50px;
            top:20px;
            left:10px;
            border:1px solid black;

        }
        html {
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
        }
        body {
            height:100%;
            background-color:deepskyblue;
            width:100%;

        }      
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- <img id="logo" src="http://mememarketmedia.s3.amazonaws.com/dank/tumblr_oamv1kgXlN1uy57v5o1_1280.jpg"/> -->
    <table>
        <tr height="12%" id="1">
            <th width="15%" id="logoarea"></th>
            <th width="85%" colspan="2" id="slogan"></th> 
        </tr>
        <tr height="8%" id="2">
            <td width="100%" colspan="3" id="navbararea"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="40%" id="3">
            <td width="100%" colspan="3" id="imgarea"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="4">
            <td width="33%" id="whyus"></td>
            <td width="34%" id="startnow"></td>
            <td width="33%" id="chatonline"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="5" height="5%">
            <td colspan="3" id="menu123"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="6" height="5%">
            <td colspan="3" id="footerarea"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>


</body>
</html>
```

So my problem explained better is that the width values from  the first first row cells and the fourth row cells change each other whenever altered, as soon as I defined the width of the cells in the first row the 4th rows cells widths start to copy the first row. Im not sure why this happened since its never happened before and I know this is probably something stupid on my part but I couldn't find an answer anywhere to this so please help!

Comment: That's the thing about using tables: the columns are all *supposed* to be the same width. If you want them to be different widths, you'll either need to use something other than tables, or multiple tables. You can't have multiple column widths in Microsoft Excel tables!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a contradiction in there:

This is the top row:

```
<tr height="12%" id="1">
    <th width="15%" id="logoarea"></th>
    <th width="85%" colspan="2" id="slogan"></th> 
</tr>
```

Note: the first cell/`th` has `width="15%"`

and this is the fourth row:

```
<tr id="4">
    <td width="33%" id="whyus"></td>
    <td width="34%" id="startnow"></td>
    <td width="33%" id="chatonline"></td>
</tr>
```

Here the first cell/`td` has `width="33%"`

Whatever a browser makes of this - it's no wonder that changing one of them affects the other in some way - cells in the same column will always have the same width (except when there is a `colspan` setting)

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior of table cells. They will line up all the way down the column.

But it looks like you’re designing with tables, and this is not the way to design a web page. Tables are for tabular data. Use proper semantic markup (divs, sections, articles, headers, figures, etc.) to structure your page, then lay out and style your page with CSS.